# Best way to display picture attachments in playframework?

Tags: java, playframework

I'm using playframework-1.2.3 and i have a data model looks like this:

```
public class Item extends Model {
  ...
  public Blob img;
}
```

The images are stored with no extensions(like "0f4fb5da-ed95-4c22-b3ec-725489285848") in my system.

I display the images this way followed the tutor:

```
<img src="@{items.getImg(i.id)}" height="210px"/>
```

But what i want is not request the controller every time i display it, is there any way allow me to display images with static file link ?

This may need two steps:
1.stored images with a extension.
2.change the file attachments dir under /public.

So , can any one help ?

Comment: I doubt that display images via controller makes the server overloaded , is that correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any real problem having it go via your controller? This actually gives you a better level of abstraction.

However, if you did want to do it statically, then you could create a new `staticDir` route, rather than moving your images into your public folder. For example

```
GET    /img/               staticDir:usrImages
```

If you need any level of security over who can see these images though, I would caution against using a public access method like this. Using a controller allows you to do a session check, to ensure the user has appropriate access to view the image.

Edit - I would suggest reading Peter Hilton's blog on this - http://www.lunatech-research.com/playframework-file-upload-blob

Comment: I doubt that display images via controller makes the server overloaded , is that correct ? Further more,i need to know how to store images with a extension since current implementation stored them with no extension.

Comment: unlikely the operation is expensive enough to add sufficient overhead. as for extension, when the file is uploaded, it is often a good idea to also save the original filename using the File object. Peter Hilton has written a good blog about this topic...see http://www.lunatech-research.com/playframework-file-upload-blob

Comment: I have seen this topic before, but it use **src="@{userPhoto(user.id)}"** to display the images too. I need **src="/photos/xxxx.png"**.

Comment: I don't understand why you need it to be the path you have specified. surely the path is irrelevant as long as the image is displayed? But if you need the path, then using the staticDir approach is your best option

Comment: I think it will be more efficient to render images if i display them with a directly path.